# Can you daisy chain 2 monitors with DP with monitor 1 connected to a KVM switch via HDMI?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, daisychaining

I currently have one monitor connected to a KVM switch with only HDMI (and USB-A for peripherals).

I want to add a 2nd monitor to my set up. I am thinking of the following set up for daisy chaining 2 monitors:

[image: Monitor scheme]

Would that be possible? Or would the connection all the way through from monitor 1 to KVM and to each PC/laptop need to be DP?

Comment: does "monitor 1" have a dp **output** port (does such a thing exist on any monitor)?

Comment: You mean you want the identical display on both monitors? Just use HDMI splitter, and, if the second only has DispalkyPort, add a HDMI->DP adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup won't work.

Even if you connect either of your hosts directly to Monitor 1 using HDMI, it still won't work.

HDMI itself does not support daisy chain. The host needs to use DP protocol to talk to Monitor 1 (also, all devices on the chain need to be at certain version of DP to support this).